# Can someone explain "remainder" in this context?

Tags: calculus

(I acknowledge the warning about a subjective question but I'm asking this straight unsubjective question for my own clarification rather than starting a documentation war!)

I was sent a code snippet for the system I am programming (Asterisk, if anyone cares), to turn seconds into minutes and seconds, partly using the function REMAINDER which is defined as:

> REMAINDER(x,y) computes the remainder of dividing x by y. The return
>   value is x - n*y, where n is the value x/y, rounded to the nearest
>   integer. If this quotient is 1/2, it is rounded to the nearest even
>   number.

But, to the surprise of the snippet provider and myself, it was chucking out some negative seconds.

So I wrote a mini test using remainder, and then modulo (%):

Output:

```
 Seconds:57 = Minutes:0 Remainder Seconds:-3 modulo seconds:57
 Seconds:60 = Minutes:1 Remainder Seconds:0 modulo seconds:0
 ...
 Seconds:84 = Minutes:1 Remainder Seconds:24 modulo seconds:24
 Seconds:87 = Minutes:1 Remainder Seconds:27 modulo seconds:27
 Seconds:90 = Minutes:1 Remainder Seconds:-30 modulo seconds:30
 Seconds:93 = Minutes:1 Remainder Seconds:-27 modulo seconds:33
 ...
 Seconds:117 = Minutes:1 Remainder Seconds:-3 modulo seconds:57
 Seconds:120 = Minutes:2 Remainder Seconds:0 modulo seconds:0
```

I filed a bug report, which was promptly closed with the following explanation:

> -3 comes from: n = x/y = 957/60 = 15.95 which rounds to 16 n*y = 16*60 = 960 x - 960 = 957-960 = -3
>
> Appears to be working as documented. I don't see an issue here.
>   Closing this one out.

I've read ["Remainder in Programming Languages"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#In_programming_languages) on Wikipedia, and I still don't get it *in relation to the explanation in the case of the system I am using*.

I have an alternative which I can use, but my own brain needs closure!

So can someone explain how, for example, 57 seconds can equal 0 minutes and -3 seconds? I could understand it if the result was 1 minute and -3 seconds, but not 0 minutes AND -3 seconds - surely that then turns 57 into -3?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you compute the minutes? If you use `REMAINDER` also for that, you may have reason to complain. If you compute the minutes as `seconds / 60` (integer division) and use `REMAINDER` only for the remaining seconds, it's just that you use incompatible tools.

Comment: Well, it also reports $90$ as $1$ minute and $-30$ seconds.  So the "minutes" item is not the quotient....it's the greatest integer in the fraction, which is different.

Comment: Just a note: When you're using `%`, the remainder `seconds % 60` will be negative if `seconds` is negative and not a multiple of 60 in several programming languages.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer - I think you may have hit the nail on the head here: the minutes are being computed by ```minutes=$[FLOOR(${seconds} / 60)])``` and ```myRemainderSec=$[REMAINDER(${seconds},60)])``` I think I'm beginning to see where the snippet might be going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** the definition of REMAINDER(x,y) is :

> computes the remainder of dividing $x$ by $y$. The return value is $x - n \cdot y$, where $n$ is the value $\dfrac x y$, **rounded to the nearest integer**

we have that the integer "nearest" to $\dfrac {57} {60}$ is not $0$ but $1$ [in fact : $1 - \dfrac {57} {60} = \dfrac {3} {60}$, while $\dfrac {57} {60} - 0 = \dfrac {57} {60}$ ].

Thus, using $1$ as $n$ in the formula above, we get :

> > $57-1 \cdot 60 = -3$.

In [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#Integer_division) the *remainder* of $\dfrac x y$ is not the "nearest" but the *smallest* integer $n$ such that $n \le \dfrac x y$.

Comment: ...and this is the kind of thing that makes me wish I'd paid more attention to math at school! I think the comments and answers have made it a little clearer, that while the function might not be correct insofar as the output it gives, I might see if I can get the docs clarified! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The remainder function you mentioned is essentially a "modulo" function.

So $$57\equiv -3\pmod{60}$$
is true. (Can you see that?)

I agree that the remainder function is rather unwieldy for real life uses, since most likely users want the positive remainder.

So the solution here is probably to write your own remainder function.

NewRemainder(x,y)=$x-\text{floor}(x/y)\cdot y$

will return the positive remainder when x is divided by y (provided x and y are both positive).

Comment: Thanks for that, @yoyostein. I think what we've arrived at is a question of the function being correct, just "could be documented better"?! Now I'm torn between two ticks because I find your explanation clearer to my case, but Mauro's is more comprehensive.I've tried to up-arrow your answer but apparently it won't show until I get 15 rep, so consider yourself up-arrowed with my thanks!

Comment: No problem, I am glad you found my explanation useful.